# Track Twitter user location using User Show API and Screen Name

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am trying to track locations of twitter users by combining User Show API and user screen name. Following is the code which is not working:

```
$.ajax({
    $("#url").append("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?").append("screen_name=bbchealth"), 
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#userloc").append(data.location);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Failure!");
        },
});
```

Comment: Are you using a browser web-development tool like Firebug for Firefox, or any other tools like in Chrome, Safari, Opera, or IE 9?  You should be getting javascript error messages, which will help...

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the ajax function correctly, with the right parameters.  I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but just from looking at [the jQuery documentation for the ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), I think you want something more like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=bbchealth", 
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#userloc").append(data.location);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Failure!");
    },
});
```

Comment: This works fine for a single screen name. My aim however is to take multiple screen names, pass them through this code individually and hence identify their locations separately. That's why I want to intake the screen name separately (in this example it's bbchealth). I am using http://jsfiddle.net/ and it's not giving me any messages.

Comment: @OKal can you provide the specific fiddle link that you're using to test with?

Comment: @OKal The [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function returns a jQuery object, not a string, and thus you cannot use it as a url like that.

Comment: @OKal also, make sure you tell jsfiddle that you want to use jQuery, not some other javascript library like mootools, I've updated the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/8SJwd/7/